# SF cartoon series with tall hairless humanoids wearing blue-gray armor

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I watched it a **long** time ago. I presume it was aired in 80s or 70s.

Facts: The main characters are humanoid beings. Male and female, and very similar looking to each other. I know they could fly by some device that looked like a board, and that they were emotionally involved with each other.

They had an odd look: tall faces and no hair at all, although I'm not certain about the female character. Both had armor on them that was tightly fit to their bodies, and was blue-grayish colored. I'm not sure, but I believe they spoke French.

That's all I can recall about it... Except that the environment was like blue-grayish also, SF buildings etc. Not quite sure they flew over some watery areas... I've been searching the net for days and more, but have found nothing. Hope someone here can point me in the right direction.

Comment: They spoke french? Where did you watch it?

Comment: Are we talking a movie or a television series? ... and were there only the two main characters (presuming protagonists)?

Comment: I was little boy so dont rely on language. It was aired in Serbia, and it had sync. I thought than, that letters from intro were French.

Comment: @ Josh Pty sure its cartoon series. But sure as hell 2 main chars, humanoids, maybe androids, blue-grayish coloured. For some reason i belive whole cartoon was in that blue-grayish manner painted. The thing that i rememer most is those 2 and their boards under their feet they used to fly, standing straith.

Comment: Do you remember the general style of the show? Was it Japanese Anime style? Was it early Disney style? Was it dark? Cheerful?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is this them?

Image from [Druillet.com](http://www.druillet.com/galerie/audiovisuel/audiovisuel.php)
and identified as *BLEU, L'ENFANT DE LA TERRE*:

[image: BLEU, L'ENFANT DE LA TERRE]

Other images available through the link above, however you have to scroll down the embedded iframe to find the cartoon in question. Not directly linkable.

On YouTube, you can find various episodes and clips. This one from [*Le Heaume Magique*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hIyNM9_ITOM) shows them standing on their boards upright and may facilitate validation a bit easier.

Comment: omg thats it! thank you so much man. hope its as lil as good as my memory tells me ^_^

Comment: @Strucker Awesome! In finding this, I was reminded of seeing this (translated) years ago... only part of it, late night on some early cable channel. My attention span wasn't very wide back then. :-/