# Old animated film with bald blue people

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

- **What is it?** An animated movie, full length (I *think*)
- **What it isn't:** It's not [La Planète sauvage/Fantastic planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Planet) and it's not [Gandahar](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095525/?ref_=nv_sr_2)
- **What made it memorable:** Animation was very trippy (at least in my memory) and main protagonist was a child with blue skin and bald head.
- **When and where did you see this film?:** Late 80's, early 90's. I saw it in the cinema, so *I guess it must* be a full length film but in that time and in my country they could actually be showing several glued together episodes of a TV-series.
- **Other details**:

I went to the cinema with a babysitter who knew French. She translated the title to me roughly as "Lue, child of Earth" (although I'm not sure that it was written in French, she didn't know English and could have read that in French by mistake). I was able to find this French TV-show called [Blue, Child of the Earth/Bleu, l'enfant de la Terre](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0872174/)  which looks painfully close apart from it being a TV-series and not a full length movie. And not actually having any child, at least, not in the first episode.

I also think that the movie started with a child being born in the core of a planet.

Movie was dubbed in Russian and I sort of remember something that the main villain (?) was saying about "отбойные барабаны", some mixture of jack-hammer and musical drum.

I'm sorry for being so vague, I'm pretty sure that my memory is hazy and I'm mixing different things into one.

Comment: You may wish to note that although 'Bleu, l'enfant de la Terre' originally ran for thirteen 22-minute episodes, it was typically shown as four feature-length episodes of 65 minutes apiece.

Comment: This sounds close to René Laloux's Gandahar, but unless you mixed up a child with a young woman, and despite it's also very creepy, it's not what your are looking for. https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095525/?ref_=nv_sr_2

Comment: @Marvin yeah, I should've mentioned it myself, it's not Gandahar.

Comment: This film? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SgCxCZNkQ9E

Comment: @JoeryJV I mentioned in the question that it isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bleu, l'Enfant de la Terre

Bleu, l'enfant de la Terre (Blue Child of the Earth) was a 1986 French animated series that ran for thirteen episodes. For cinema showing, the last 4 episodes were usually recut as one feature length movie.

Episode one here:

Similar to this sci fi question:

[SF cartoon series with tall hairless humanoids wearing blue-gray armor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13237/sf-cartoon-series-with-tall-hairless-humanoids-wearing-blue-gray-armor)

Comment: I actually mentioned it in the question and it did already came up in the comments.

Comment: That's the movie. Three last episodes of tv series were cut for Russian and slavic markets into a full length movie.

Comment: I can't deny that it's possible. I was hoping for other alternatives; Blue, Child of Earth is hard to find in full. If you watched it, can you please clarify, was there actually a Blue Child in it?

Comment: There is, although it happens at about half the series mark. He gets a son with main blue girl and then flies around with kid and has adventures.

Comment: Thank you! Memory works in weird ways, huh.

Answer (score 7):

Is it *Strit og Stumme*, aka *[Dreaming of Paradise](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0124147/)* (1987)?

> In the future, pollution has driven humans deep under ground, where they tell legends of the paradise above. Two kids must find the path to the surface, while avoiding the humanoid, militaristic rats seeking to steal their dreams.

I was searching for it for a while and finally found it

Comment: That's not it, sorry :( That is a really interesting example of something similar to what I described in my question but not remotely similar to what I remember :) I guess I'm not very good at describing things.

Answer (score 3):

Could this be [Blue, Child of the Earth](http://machinerobo.wikia.com/wiki/Bleu,_l%27enfant_de_la_Terre) (AKA Bleu, l'Enfant de la Terre). It featured the "Rock Lords" (of Gobots fame) in supporting roles.

Although it originally ran for thirteen 22-minute episodes, it was typically shown as four feature-length episodes of 65 minutes apiece.

Comment: OP mentioned it but was unsure due to the episodes' length thing.

Comment: @Jenayah - Hence why I've mentioned that it was broadcast in feature-length chunks.

Comment: @Valorum I can't deny that it's possible. I was hoping for other alternatives; Blue, Child of Earth is hard to find in full. If you watched it, can you please clarify, was there actually a Blue Child in it?